# Tools to assist with continual Java to C# Conversion

Tags: c#, java

These days, many projects have started their life written in Java.  Some of them are eventually converted to C# for incorporation in .NET.  Examples that come to mind are log4net, nhibernate and db4o.

Including sharpen (which is db4o's tool) have you seen and/or used any tools that make continual conversion manageable.  I'd go so far as to say anything that requires more than about a 2 month slip from the original product release isn't really all that useful for continual conversion.

Comment: This question is pretty old, but let me give you the final disposition I ended up with.  I wrote an application that assisted with the conversion of actual Java code to C#.  There were many key points, but simple things like loss of comments and interpretation of meaning were so specific that I landed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IKvm](http://www.ikvm.net/)

IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET Framework. It includes the following components:

```
* A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET
* A .NET implementation of the Java class libraries
* Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability
```

Comment: IKVM does not _convert_ the projects to C#, but allows them to run on the .NET runtime instead of a JVM.